# How do you prevent Papertrail logs from wrapping?

Tags: papertrail-app

Is there a preference that I'm missing?

Comment: I got a response from their tech support, that this is an intended feature so that they can:
 1) Maintain performance [How do you handle extremely long lines in a browser?Text editors have issues with this, too.] 
2) Prevent horizontal scrolling. Papertral really does not want that in their UI.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible [ 2019 ]

maybe Greasemonkey can help https://www.greasespot.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "truncate message" feature which worked great for me. [image]